# Binding to ngModel in Ionic Framework

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am having a difficulty in binding ngModel to ion-segment while building an ionic application. Below is the heading of the error I have received :

**Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-segment'**

I intend to use Shared Module for two modules. One more shared module I have created using standard HTML tags and it worked as required. But this one seems to be causing error.

I tried many solutions suggested by other users in similar kind of problems but none of them seem to solve the problem. Here is my shared Module I am using:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SomeClass } from './some-class';

@NgModule({
    imports : [
        CommonModule,
        IonicPageModule.forChild(SomeClass),
    ],
    declarations : [SomeClass],
    exports : [SomeClass]
})

export class SharedModule{

}
```

The HTML file for the same is :

```
 <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="XXX" (click)="someMethod()">
   <ion-segment-button value="A"> A </ion-segment-button> 
   <ion-segment-button value="B"> B </ion-segment-button> 
   <ion-segment-button value="C"> C </ion-segment-button> 
 </ion-segment>
```

Note :  This is only a part of HTML file to be included in a whole other page.

The Component file :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'some-class',
  templateUrl: 'some-class.html'
})
export class SomeClass {

  XXX: String;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) { }   

}
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong and what should I do to solve the problem?

Note: I have tried importing FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule and also tried exporting the references, but nothing helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *ngModel* directive comes from the *FormsModule*.

The error is saying that it is unable to find the directive ("unknown"), which is almost always an indicator of missing references. In this case, *FormsModule*, which has the necessary libraries to bind the *ngModel* directive to any HTML element.

Angular 4 in combination with feature modules (if you are for instance using a shared-module) requires you to also export the ReactiveFormsModule to work.

I think the code for the module should be:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; //CHANGE(ADD)
import { SomeClass } from './some-class';

@NgModule({
    imports : [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, //CHANGE (ADD)
        IonicPageModule.forChild(SomeClass),
    ],
    declarations : [SomeClass],
    exports : [SomeClass, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule]
})

export class SharedModule{

}
```

Comment: Already tried to import FormsModule, but without any luck.  Thanks for your effort. By any chance, could there be any problem with Ionic tags binding?

Comment: You are most welcome Dhruv! I think, because we have a SharedModule in the play, there is also the need to import the ReactiveFormsModule. Have you tried that?

Comment: Also since a shared module, the imported modules need to be exported,  I believe. Updated the code.

Comment: Just noticed, you are not exporting the common module. Could you please try it out by adding the Common module to the export array once?

Comment: Did just now. Problem still there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170099/discussion-between-bindebug-and-dhruv-singhal).

Comment: After some server restarts, adding the references seemed to work properly. Thanks for the answer.